# how to assign value to lookup fields in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

i have two objects KNDY4__Sales_Order__c and KNDY4__Bill_to__c.these two are linked through lookup relationship.i am trying to insert one order record as follows

```
`KNDY4__Sales_Order__c order=New KNDY4__Sales_Order__c();
order.KNDY4__Ship_to__c ='a14q0000001LnIeAAK';
order.KNDY4__Bill_to__r.Predicted_External_ID__c ='CN-0222741-Sold To';
order.KNDY4__Company__c ='a0l1N00000BQQKF';
Insert order;`
```

i am geting error as {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}.
how to assign values to lookup field.can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

When linking a record based on an external id, the relationship field needs to be set to an sObject with the external id, and not just the value of the id itself.

On line 3, since `KNDY4__Bill_to__c` is a lookup field to a custom object possibly named `KNDY4__Customer__c`, you should set the value of the lookup to an instance of that object, e.g.

```
order.KNDY4__Bill_to__r = new KNDY4__Customer__c(KNDY4__Predicted_External_ID__c ='CN-0222741-Sold To');
```

Comment: sorry, i was mistaken.KNDY4__Bill_to__c is not another object its a custom field in KNDY4__Sales_Order__c and has lookup relation with customer object.so on inserting new order i need to populate customer bill details also.so what changes i need to do. thanks